# WiFiClientSecure readString function slow

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a sketch that requests a device token from Facebook in order to authenticate a Wemos D1 Mini.

All in all, I want to reproduce the following, which gives me a device code in less than a second:

> curl https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/device/login -d
>   "type=device_code&access_token=MYTOKEN"

I set up the following sketch which works albeit very slowly. It fetches the device token in about 17 seconds. 
It seems that String response = client.readString(); is the culprit.

Can any offer advice on why that could be, and how to possibly remedy it?

Thank you kindly,

Nate

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

WiFiClientSecure client; //edited

void setup() {
    connect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PWD); //edited
    Serial.println(getFBDeviceToken());
}

void connect(const char* WIFI_SSID, const char* WIFI_PWD) {

  delay(1000);
  WiFi.persistent(false);
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);    

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_DISCONNECTED) {    
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PWD);
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println("connecting...");
    }
    Serial.println("\r\n"+WiFi.localIP());
  }    
}

String getFBDeviceToken(){

  //Connect to FB SSL
  if(!client.connect(host, httpPort)){
    return "** Failed to connect **";
  }

  client.println("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: " + String(host));
  client.println("User-Agent: ESP8266/1.0");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
  client.print("Content-Length: ");
  client.println(data.length());
  client.println();
  client.println(data);

  String response = client.readString(); 
  int bodypos =  response.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 4;


  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response.substring(bodypos));

  String device_token = root[String("user_code")];

  return device_token;
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare `client`?

Comment: Note that `WebSocketClient::readString` is non-blocking and may return empty.
https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/blob/master/src/WebSocketClient.cpp#L277

Comment: Hi, I edited the sketch above to reflect the parts I omitted. The sketch works, it doesn't return empty, but it's very slow!

Comment: It should already help to `WifiClient::flush` the outgoing request.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I notice no difference by adding a flush(), it still takes 15 seconds to get the json back from Facebook (as opposed to less than a sec from the command line) :(

Comment: https is really slow on esp8266s, you can reproxy it locally to use http instead, which is really fast from your lan.

Comment: @dandavis hi, not sure I’m following, what do you mean by reproxy locally? Could you recommend some reading?

Comment: you run a php script locally that fetches over the web via https and serves the response with plain http, from the safety of your LAN.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is still relevant for you but I faced the same situation and I believe I found a solution. If it is not relevant to you, perhaps it will help some other, especially given that the default WiFiClientSecure library will soon be switched to BearSSL and no support is currently being given for the existing implementation.

Although I did not manage to speed up readString function, I used the  [`WiFiClientSecure::read(uint8_t *buf, size_t size)`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/464bdccf419a284c22c9ad79f5de0efc79ca7bfd/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClientSecureAxTLS.cpp#L190-L197) function to get the data from the server:

```
// Buffer size, 128 bytes in this case
#define RESP_BUFFER_LENGTH 128
// Pointer to actual buffer
uint8_t * _buffer = new uint8_t[RESP_BUFFER_LENGTH];
// String to hold the final response
String _responseString = "";
// If info is still available
while (wifiClient.available())
{
    // Fill the buffer and make a note of the total read length 
    int actualLength = wifiClient.read(_buffer, RESP_BUFFER_LENGTH);
    // If it fails for whatever reason
    if(actualLength <= 0)
    {
        // Handle as you see fit
        return -1;
    }
    // Concatenate the buffer content to the final response string
    // I used an arduino String for convenience
    // but you can use strcat or whatever you see fit
    _responseString += String((char*)_buffer).substring(0, actualLength);  
}
// Clear buffer memory
delete[] _buffer;
```

I don't know why the regular readString() is so slow, but this method is considerably faster, with my relatively small messages (~50 bytes) the response is being read almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If look under hood, `readString()` always reads all data and when it reads the last symbol it stucks with server communication.

To avoid it you should not read last one symbol somehow.

I read headers by using `readStringUntil('\n')` and searching `Content-Length` header.

When headers has been read, just use `readBytes` with content-length.
HTTP request now took around 150ms.